# "The first step in making" vs. "the first step on making" vs. "the first step at making"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, in-on, at-on

I have this sentence:

> I strongly believe that the first step **in** making the most efficient solution for any problem is analyzing it well.

Would it be better to use either of the following?

> - I strongly believe that the first step **on** making the most efficient solution for any problem is analyzing it well.
> - I strongly believe that the first step **at** making the most efficient solution for any problem is analyzing it well.

The context is as follows:

> First of all, I concentrate on understanding the big picture of any problem. I always try to recognize all the factors that have caused the problem. Then, I start planning the solution at a very high level in order to create  long-term benefits. I strongly believe that the first step in making the most efficient solution to any problem is analyzing it well. In my opinion, "What to do" is much more important than "How to do".

Comment: You could also say _to_ or _toward(s)_. Don't forget that no actual _steps_ are being stepped here; there are no feet in this sentence. Consequently, which preposition one uses here depends on which metaphor one is employing here. _On_ and _at_ are probly wrong, though; since one steps _on_ a flat surface only, it would only work if you'd previously deployed a _Stairway_ metaphor. And _step at_ is not normally used.

Comment: Then I would say _... the first step to take in creating the most ..._ because "taking a step" sets the metaphor, and "creating" emphasizes the fact that there is no efficient solution available yet.

Comment: @Marco, John: But there's nothing inherently wrong with *in* here. Arguably it could be more appropriate, since OP's preceding context is a list of [other] "things" that are also "in" the ingredients of "making the most efficient solution".

Comment: I agree; but _to make_ is normally not used when there's a more specific word available to reinforce a metaphor. And the _in_ fits well with a verb like _the step to take in `V`-ing_, but not so good with a noun phrase alone _the step in `V`-ing_.

Comment: i thank you for the whole discussion but please make a final desission and i give you the whole context, i really need to know and learn and i always appreciate your help , thank you too mush

Comment: You do not make a solution. Unless you are a chemist. A solution is *found*, not *made*. And I have to wonder why you are not considering *to* or *of* — which are poor choices but at least make some sense —, yet do consider *at* and *on* — which make no sense at all. Whenever presenting a list of options you should explain *why* you think each of them is an option at all. Otherwise we're just presented with a random list that's as good as any, and which nine times out of ten does not even contain the actual answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Of the options you offered, "to", "on" and "at", the first is certainly the best, and I have heard it used many times in that context. The other two don't make much sense. However, I'd offer an alternative:

```
... the first step toward making the most efficient solution...
```

It seems to me to work well with the metaphorical walk to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The noun **step** (meaning an action in a series of actions culminating in an achievement) can be used with in, to/towards, and on. However, they are distinct in what they mean.

Step in a process/in a direction: The new law is a step in the right direction.

Step to/towards a goal: The new law is the first step towards eradicating drug abuse. The new law is the first step to eradicate drug abuse (In the second sentence, **to** is not really a preposition. It's part of the infinitive verb, **to eradicate**.

Step on the ladder: The first step on the corporate ladder